# How to prevent inline JavaScript execution? (Chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension to block some scripts from certain websites.
For external scripts, I can use beforeload event to block them.

However how to block inline scripts?

I need to run some content scripts, so I guess disabling JavaScript isn't a choice for me.

Comment: Please try to include more information, and refer to this: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I don't know what to try, so I asked.